# Keycloak Error -Forbidden You don't have access to the requested resource while updating client

Tags: keycloak, load-balancing, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, istio-gateway

Keycloak was installed using bitnami helm chart.
It was working fine when we are using Hard Load balancer like

spec:
hosts:

- "keycloak.myhost.com"
  gateways:
- istio-svcs-gateway
  http:
- match:

  - uri:
    prefix: /
    route:
  - destination:
    port:
    number: 80
    host: Service-name.keycloak.svc.cluster.local

above is working fine when it is hard load balancer.

But when using soft load balancer like

- match:

  - uri:
    prefix: /auth
    rewrite:
    uri: /auth

  route:

  - destination:
    host: service-name.keycloak.svc.cluster.local
    port:
    number: 80

By using this I can login as keycloak admin and also I am accesible to create realm and clients but when I am trying to update changes in client(validate URL) or deleting realm it will redirected to
**Forbidden You don't have access to the requested resource while updating client.**

What I have tried to login as admin
while installing chart I added

- name: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
  value: "https://keycloak.xxx"

in extraEnvVars Section

this helped me to access the login page when using soft load balancer
but I cannot update any client data